# Mix build flags for several configurations in CMake

Tags: cmake, compiler-flags

According to CMake documentation [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html), we can use the build type to specify our own build types, adding flags to our custom build depending on the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` option.

For example, `if CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE == Profile`, CMake will use `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_PROFILE` for the build flags.

I would like to know if there is any way to "inherit" build flags from another build type. For example, I want a trace and debug build and a trace and release build. Is it possible to do something like `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Trace_Debug` which adds `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_TRACE` to the build? I guess this can have some problems as it would allow the project to have contradictory build flags, but nothing prohibits to add `-O1` and `-O3` to our flags now, so that problem already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing in CMake like "inheriting" a build type.

> Is it possible to do something like `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Trace_Debug` which adds `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_TRACE` to the build?

Just define a (new) variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_TRACE_DEBUG` and set its value appropriately. When setting the value of the variable you may use values from other variables:

```
# Combine values of two variables into the single one.
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_TRACE_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_TRACE}")
```

It is up to you to remove conflicting flags from the resulted variable. CMake has no knowledge about conflicting flags, it just passes them to the compiler tool.